# add a style to System.Web.UI.Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, attributes, styles

I am building a whole bunch of different controls from a database schema. 
When I run through the controls in my code behind, I want to pass the control and the styles (as a string from the database... eg. "color:white;width:50px;height:10px;") to a re-usable function.

This is how I thought I should go about it :

```
 Sub AddStylesToControl(ByRef ctrl As Control, Styles As String)

    'split styles string by semi colon
    Dim StyleArr() As String
    Dim count As Integer
    StyleArr = Styles.Split(";")
    For count = 0 To StyleArr.Length - 1

        '//ctrl.Attributes.Add("style", "color: red;")
        ctrl.Attributes.Add("style", StyleArr(count))
    Next

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, on the line "ctrl.Attributes.Add("style", StyleArr(count))"  I get an error:
'attributes' is not a member of 'system.web.ui.control'
I understand what the error means, but does anyone know of a way around this ?

Many thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `WebControl` rather than `Control`.  `WebControl` is derived from `Control` but includes the `Attributes` property.

Also, the "style" attribute of the control should contain a single string containing the CSS delimited by `;`.  So passing the entire string as you have it in your database is enough, you do not need to do any more processing.

So your function should simply look something like...

```
Sub AddStylesToControl(ByRef ctrl As WebControl, ByVal styles As String)
    ctrl.Attributes("style") = styles
End Sub
```

I have changed it to a direct setting (rather than `Add`) as this will overwrite any existing `"style"`.  Using `Attributes.Add` will fail if the `"style"` already exists in the collection.

Comment: I haven't had time to run the code through yet, but that certainly solved the error I was getting during compilation...  Thanks a lot dude, I really appreciate your help !!

Comment: @wotney No worries, just remember we appreciate upvotes and accepted answers in return ;-)